# Javascript : insert data into a Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'm trying to insert values taken from Php to a Google Chart, like so :

```
var JSVAR1 = "<?php echo $PHPVAR1; ?>";
window.alert(JSVAR1); // data displayed fine
data.addRows([
  ['Pie Section 1', 51],
  ['Pie Section 2', 7],
  ['Pie Section 3', 4]
]);
```

I would like to replace the "51" by JSVAR1 (make an echo or something). I already tried several things, but nothing works. How can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

EDIT : here is the list of what doesn't work :

```
['Pie Section 1', JSVAR1]
['Pie Section 1', "<?php echo $PHPVAR1; ?>"]
['Pie Section 1', "<?php echo json_encode($PHPVAR1); ?>"]
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You're trying to replace the `51` with the `JSVAR1` variable?
Does the window.alert show the correct value?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Window.alert displays the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straight forward:

```
var JSVAR1 = "<?php echo $PHPVAR1; ?>";
window.alert(JSVAR1); // data displayed fine
data.addRows([
  ['Pie Section 1', JSVAR1],
  ['Pie Section 2', 7],
  ['Pie Section 3', 4]
]);
```

Comment: the comment near the window.alert() says the value is displayed correctly. So, the first (and the only thing I can think about with the available info) is the most obvious one :)

Comment: if instead of 51 you put another hard coded value, is that reflected in your graph?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. It was a problem of data parsing. Solved like this :

```
var JSVAR1 ="<?php echo $PHPVAR1; ?>";
data.addRows([
['Pie section 1', parseInt(JSVAR1)],
//...
]);
```

Conclusion : if anyone has problems with Google Charts, be sure to parse your data, even if it seems useless.

Comment: well when you're storing it as a var, you are storing it as a string (it's wrapped in `"`). Google charts requires you to match the data type set on that column, so you can either parse like you did, or cast it like `(int) JSVAR1`